# What is the pattern for Google Cloud Functions to implement mutex

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-functions

I'm using https triggered Google Cloud Functions to handle client requests to perform database writes. The data is structured in a way that most in parallel writes will not result in corruption.

There are few cases where I need to prevent multiple write actions to happen at once for the same item. What are the common patterns to lock access to some resource on the function level. I'm looking for some "mutex-like" functionality.

I was thinking of some external service that could grant or deny access to the resource for requesting function instances, but the connection overhead would be huge - handshake each time etc.

Added an example as requested. In this specific case, restructuring the data to keep the track of updates isn't a suitable solution.

```
import * as admin from "firebase-admin";

function updateUserState(userId: string) {
    // Query current state
    admin
        .database()
        .ref()
        .child(`/users/${userId}/state`)
        .once("value")
        .then(snapshot => {
            return snapshot.val() || 0;
        })
        .then(currentState => 
            // Perform some operation
            modifyStateAsync(currentState)
        )
        .then(newState => {
            admin
                .database()
                .ref()
                .child(`/users/${userId}/state`)
                .set(newState);
        });
}
```

Comment: This sounds like a [XY problem](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem). It's a lot more likely that someone can help with your concrete problem, if you show the minimal code that reproduces the actual problem.

Comment: As requested a more concrete example has been added.

Comment: If you want to write a new value based on an existing value, use a [transaction](https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/web/read-and-write#save_data_as_transactions). Aside from that: the final two `then()` clauses don't return any value, so if you run this code in Cloud Functions, it has no way to know when your write to the database is done.

Answer (score 1):

In the Google Cloud there is an elegant way to have a global distributed [mutex](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mutual_exclusion) for a [critical section](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Critical_section) in a Cloud Function:

[gcslock](https://github.com/mco-gh/gcslock)

This is a library written in Go language, hence available for Cloud Functions written in Go, that utilises atomicity guarantees of the Google Cloud Storage service. This approach is apparently not available in AWS because of the lack of such guarantees in the S3 service.

The tool is not applicable for every use case. Acquiring and releasing the lock are operations of order of 10ms, which might be too much for high speed processing use cases.

For a typical batch process, that is not time critical, the tool provides pretty interesting option of guaranteeing that your Cloud Function is not running concurrently over the same target resource. Just create the lock file in GCS with the name that is unique for the operation that you'd like to put into the critical section and release it once its done (or rely on the GCS object lifecycle management to clean the locks up).

Please see more considerations and pros and cons in the original tool GitHub project.

There is also apparently an [implementation](https://github.com/thinkingmachines/gcs-mutex-lock) of the same in Python.

Here is a nice [article](https://www.joyfulbikeshedding.com/blog/2021-05-19-robust-distributed-locking-algorithm-based-on-google-cloud-storage.html) that summarises use cases for distributed locking on GCP in particular.

Answer (score 0):

This is not a pattern that you want to implement in Cloud Functions.  Restricting the parallelism of Cloud Functions would limit its scalability, which is counter to the way Cloud Functions works.  To learn more about how Cloud Functions scales, [watch this video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=rCpKxpIMg6o&t=1s).

If you have a database that needs to have some protection against concurrent access, you should be using the database's own transaction features.  Pretty much every database that provides concurrent access to data also provides some ability to perform atomic transactions.  Use these transactions, and let the serverless container scale up and down in the way it sees fit.

Comment: I appreciate repeating common truths, but please read the question. I emphasised in the very first sentence that this is rather an exception, not the way to use functions/ lambdas. Cloud Datastore or Realtime Database don't provide an option to perform true transactions, besides the operation consists of read and write.

Comment: Realtime Database and Cloud Firestore do provide transactions that are suitable for use with Cloud Functions.  There is no exception to the rule of how Cloud Functions scales.  It sounds like perhaps your question is actually going to be about those transactions, not about CF.

Comment: Realtime Database Admin SDK doesn't provide transactions, besides the whole operation consists of read and write, during which the underlying data shouldn't change. This is why, even if using a different database, it's not a task with a transaction.

Comment: That's not true.  The Admin SDK [does provide transactions](https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/admin/save-data#section-transactions) that work just like the client libraries.  Transactions in Realtime Database do not lock the database.  They are optimistic locks and will get retried or canceled in the event that data is changed by another transaction, or a client does not use a transaction to change data.  If this concurrency model doesn't work for you, consider restructuring your data, or consider using a different database.

Comment: Using an external service to "lock the entire database" is a really bad idea and will have ramifications on how well your application scales.

Comment: Those are not transactions on the database level, but several round trips between the client and server (for client it requires read permission). The application stores many resource types, and for 95% of them the model works fine. I don't want to "lock the entire database". Imagine a collection that represents daily calendars of several individuals. It's ok to operate (read->process->write) in parallel on different days or individuals, but not to operate(read->process->write) in parallel from 2 functions on the same day. I want to fail fast a function if someone else is writing same resource.

Comment: Then consider using a different database the supports the locking semantics you require.

Comment: Cloud Functions can process and interact with resources that you cannot choose/change, do not provide transactional guarantees and are not databases but still need concurrent access control. E.g. the GCP resources themselves.
The original ask for a common pattern for Cloud Functions makes sense.